# Convert to raw Hex (not in hex string) from int

Tags: python

How do I convert int to hex (not in hex string) in python. actually I have to use it in a function. Ex:
`fun(0xfb1,0x1)`
I cannot pass '0xfb1' instead of 0xfb1. i.e. I can't pass hex string, I have to use raw hex, even I cannot hard-code the hex value I will have to store it in a variable

Comment: Well hex is only a representation of an integer number, like binary or decimal. Can you please show us what is the intent of your function?

Answer (score 0):

Hex is just a number representation, it's not a type like `int`. You can express literals in hex like you are doing, but that will be interpreted as an `int`, like if you where writing it in decimal.

It would be helpful if you gave some more detail about your use case.